# How to upload only pdf type file in Yii framework using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, yii

I tried to upload pdf type files using CMultifileUpload widget.here is my form code:

```
<div class="row" id="file_upload" style="margin-left:20%; margin-bottom:2%;">
         <?php
            $this->widget('CMultiFileUpload',array(
                'name'        => 'files',
                'accept'      => 'pdf',
                'max'         => 1,
                'htmlOptions' => array('size' => 25),
            ));             
            echo CHtml::htmlButton('Upload',array(
            'onclick'=>'javascript: send();', // on submit call JS send() function
            'id'=> 'post-submit-btn', // button id 'newcreate'
            'class'=>'btn btn-primary',
        ));
        ?>

    </div>
```

it uploads all types of  files.but i want to upload only pdf type files using this widget.how can i do it ?can any one help me with code example.

Comment: Show your server side allowed type. (your model rules)

Comment: how can i do that? can tell me more specifically..thanks @scaisEdge

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/

Comment: hi @ineersa the link you provided is not working...browser can not load the link.....i tried several time with different browser (chrom,firefox,Opera,Safari)...can you please provide me with another link...

Comment: show the code of the model related to this view..

Comment: hi @scaisEdge i have solved the file uploading issue by customizing the CMultiFileUpload widget....... thanks for your suggestion though...

Answer (score 0):

In the `_form.php` file inside view:

```php
$this->widget('CMultiFileUpload',[
       'model' => $model,
       'attribute' => 'pdf_file',
       'accept' => 'pdf',
       'file' => 'PDF file label',
       'max' => 1, 
       'remove' => 'Remove file',
       'htmlOptions' => ['accept' => 'application/pdf'],
       'denied' => 'ERROR. Incorrect format.', 
       'duplicate' => 'ERROR. Duplicated file'
  ]);
```

In the `Controller.php` file (as example the **create** action):

```php
public function actionCreate(){
    $model = new FooModel;
    $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
    if(isset($_POST['FooModel'])){
      $model->attributes = $_POST['FooModel'];
      try{
        $pdf_files = CUploadedFile::getInstancesByName('FooModel');
        if (count($pdf_files) > 0) {
          foreach ($pdf_files as $file) {
            /*
             * $file->name: original name
             * $file->tempName: name in /temp
             * $file->type: e.g. image/png
             * $file->size: size/1024 => kbs
             * $file->error: 0 = no error
             * $file->extensionName
             */
            if (!$f->getHasError()) {
              if(strtolower($f->getExtensionName()) == 'pdf'){
                // do things with file
              }
              else{
                // set errors
                $model->setError('pdf_file', 'Incorrect format');
              }
            }else{
              echo 'Level file error';
            }
          }// foreach
        }// if files
      }
      catch(CDbException $e){
        throw new CHttpException(400, 'Some error');
      }
      catch(Exception $e){
        throw new CHttpException($e->getCode(), $e->getMessage());
      }
    }// if post
    $this->render('create', ['model' => $model]);
  }
```